# Storing comma seperated Foreign Key values in a table in mysql (getting 1452 error)

Tags: mysql

I am having two tables brand and vendors.

The **brand table** is as follows (brand_id is VARCHAR):

```
brand_id      brand_name
---------    --------------
01               KFC
02               MCD
03               Cream stone
```

I created another table vendor which has **brand_id as foreign key** with statement:

```
CREATE TABLE vendor(vendor_id VARCHAR(20), 
        name VARCHAR(50), 
        brand_id VARCHAR(10), 
        PRIMARY KEY (vendor_id), 
        FOREIGN KEY(brand_id) REFERENCES vendor_brand(brand_id));
```

Now my requirement is i want to store comma separated brand_id's in **vendor table** as:

```
vendor_id         name                  brand_id
---------    --------------          ---------------
1               Hi Bakers               01, 02
2               Test Confectioners      02
3               Cream Parlour           01, 02, 03
```

Iam getting **Error #1452** on inserting. How to make comma separated values?

Comment: Do **not** store comma separated values - just don't. It's bad design and you will *never* be able to apply proper foreign key constraints.

Comment: It is not a good idea. You shold normalize your database model. If you want to store the brand_id as a csv- value you have to remove the forein key.

Comment: removed foreign key. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That does not work to store multiple foreign keys in a column. And you should absolutely not do it even if it weren't keys. Never, never, never store multiple values in one column! This will only give you headaches with your future selects and it is really slow performance-wise.

A better approach would be to have another new table called

```
vendor_brands
-------------
vendor_id
brand_id
```

Comment: if I will go with comma separated logic then what kind problem occurs in future ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad